# how to concatenate three strings first two characters automatically in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
I have three columns in a table like name,village,state.
Name='Samba Siva'
Village='Kodur'
State='Andra pradesh'
```

I want to cancatenate three columns  like first two characters of first column and first       characters of second column and First character of third column and current year last two   digits.

I have tried like this

```
select right(replace(name,2)+Cast(cast(coalesce(max(village),0) as varchar) as varchar),2) customercode
from(select top 1 customercode from K_FS_DistributorDetails order by customercode)r;
```

but its not working. i.e: I want output like 
      code='SAKOA14'.
Here 14 is the current year last two digits.
    Please tell me how can I write query please help me.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT TOP 1 UPPER(LEFT(Name, 2) + LEFT(Village, 2) + LEFT(State, 1) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, YEAR(GETDATE()) % 100)) code
  FROM K_FS_DistributorDetails
 ORDER BY customercode DESC
```

Output:

```
|    CODE |
|---------|
| SAKOA14 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31a9c/2)** demo